# mysql update multiple id/value pairs with one statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

If I have a mysql table with the 2 columns:

```
ID   Date
1    2012-03-05
2    2012-02-21
3    2013-06-12
4    2011-01-15
5    2013-02-23
```

and I have an array of random updates such as

```
$arr = array('2'=>'2013-03-23','4'=>'2013-03-19','5'=>'2011-08-09');
```

(where the index is the ID and the value is the date)

is there a way to update the table with one statement?

the reason I am doing this, is because I need to make hundreds+ of changes and single updates would be alot of statements.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but maybe someone got any way to achieve it.

Comment: If you insert the array to a tempTable then it can be achieved easily

Comment: @SashiKant not sure what you mean. any links i can read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ID` is unique or a primary key, you can do

```
INSERT INTO `Table` (ID, `Date`)
VALUES ('2', '2013-03-23'), ('4', '2013-03-19'), ('5', '2011-08-09')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Date` = VALUES(`Date`)
```

Note that this might affect the auto increment value and it might insert new records into the table.

Comment: `Date` does not need to be unique. `ID` must be unique or a primary key.

Comment: but bro how to run this query in "codeigniter" ? [Here Posting Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949135/how-to-insert-and-update-existing-array-data-with-one-single-query-in-codeignite)